# How do I portforward for IIS8 in my tp-link router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

How do I portforward for IIS8 in my tp-link router
I'm using tplink router model No tl-wr740n for internet connection. when I connect

directly to internet without using my router, I am able to open the page hosted in my IIS8

using following address.
/default.html
but as opposed to it when I connect to internet from my router, I'm unable to open the

said page using the above mentioned adress.

I have used the following setting in forwarding but it didn't help at all

[image]

I would be really greatful for the one who helps me out solving this problem

Comment: fist, set you protocol to TCP. no need to expose your network to UDP for www traffic. Your nat rule looks valid. have you tried rebooting the router? what does www.canyouseeme.com say about your TCP\80?

Comment: I have set protocol to TCP and Rebooted my router. what do you mean by canyouseeme.com. what do I need to do for www.canyouseeme.com to say something about my TCP/80?

Comment: am able to open the hosted page using my local ip address using http://192.168.1.2/default.html. but unable to open the same page using my internet ipaddress using 111.119.177.197/default.html

Comment: glad you got it figured out. for future reference, www.canyouseeme.com has an online port testing tool, so you can use it to see if people outside your network can see and connect to your service ports. check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because your router is using port 80 for its web management port.  You should change the web management port to something else or change the incoming port you want forwarded.

If you change the web management port, you will only be able to access your router on that new port.

If you change the incoming port to be forwarded to port 8080 for example, then you must use that port for every request; example: http://my.homesite.com:8080/

Comment: thanx. let me try this then I would inform you about the situation

Comment: That's probably because your router is using port 80 for its web management por. this worked thanks alot